# Discrepancy in capitalization between local and remote

Tags: git, github

On a Git/GiHub project, I had several files named where acronyms were all capital letters. For example:

PEBKAC.js:

```
export const PEBKAC = ...
```

other.js:

```
import { PEBKAC } from './PEBKAC'
```

I decided that the capitalization from long acronyms was visually unappealing and renamed the file in my editor (VSCode, on MacOS) and the object to:

Pebkac.js:

```
export const pebkac = ...
```

other.js:

```
import { pebkac } from './Pebkac'
```

I committed the change, and I noticed that the file `PEBKAC.js` was tagged as "modified", not "renamed", but I nevertheless committed and pushed.

Now, viewing the file in GitHub, I see it as `PEBKAC.js`, which wouldn't work due to the import, while locally I see it as `Pebkac.js`. Git does not see a difference between the remote and local. How did this discrepancy happen, and how can I fix it?

---

Problem solved, see accepted answer for details. Solution:

```
git mv PEBKAC.js Pebkac.js
```

Comment: How are you asceraining that the files on GitHub still have the old capitalization?  Did you manually inspect the branch after you pushed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they appear that way on the GitHub site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't actually rename the files.  Well, you did, but you didn't.  Hang on: this can get confusing.

*Git* doesn't really work with files, not quite the way your computer does anyway.  Git works with *commits*, and `git push` sends commits.  GitHub therefore has *no* files on it; it just has commits.

Each commit does, however, contain a snapshot of *all* of your files, in a Git-ified format.  These snapshots are read-only and compressed, and only Git itself can actually use them.  To make them useful on your *computer*, your Git extracts any given commit to a work area.

Git complicates this a bit more: on your computer, Git first extracts the commit to Git's *index*.  The index is actually a data file.  It contains file names, but not in the form that your computer uses.  For instance, a file named `dir/sub/file.ext` is literally just stored as `dir/sub/file.ext` in the index.  Your *computer* demands that Git create a folder / directory named `dir`, then, inside that, create one named `sub`, then, inside that, create `file.ext`, so that there is a file named `file.ext` in a folder named `sub` in a folder named `dir`.  (You might refer to this as `dir\sub\file.ext`, even.)  But in the *index*, it's just a *file* whose name is `dir/sub/file.ext`.

File names in the index are case sensitive, and use forward slashes (always, even on Windows).

File names on your *computer*, having been stored into folders, are—at least on *your* computer; some differ—*not* case sensitive.  That is, once `dir\sub\file.ext` exists, use of `DIR\suB\fIlE.ExT` accesses that same file.  So it doesn't matter if you change the case of these on-disk files, because to your computer, `file.ext`, `File.ext`, and `FILE.EXT` are all the same file.

Your Git knows about this, and therefore can leave the old-case names in place in the index, even though you used whatever method you use on your computer to make them different.

If you use `git mv`, you can get Git to update the *index copy* of the file's name (while also updating the file's name in the file system).  This may require a relatively modern Git; some older Git versions are less capable here.

For instance, on my Mac (which uses forward slashes, but also defaults to case-insensitive file system):

```
sh-3.2$ ls
File.Ext        README.md
sh-3.2$ mv File.Ext file.ext
sh-3.2$ ls
README.md       file.ext
sh-3.2$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Note the lack of a rename.  But now:

```
sh-3.2$ git mv File.Ext file.ext
sh-3.2$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    File.Ext -> file.ext
```

(The Git on my Mac for testing here is a bit out of date, 2.20.1, but that's clearly late enough to make `git mv` work right.)

When you make a *new* commit, Git uses whatever is in the index, not what is in the work-tree.  If the files in the *index* have the old-case names, the new commit will also have the old-case names.

It's not always easy to see what's in the index—`git status` *shortens* the output on purpose, by showing you what's *different* rather than what is there—and if you do this in a big project it will print out too much data, but, to see what's in the index, in its relatively raw form, use `git ls-files --stage`:

```
sh-3.2$ git ls-files --stage
100644 5f6a92a7cb8dec274ebbd7a471ba4101766336ab 0       README.md
100644 d2b181532c33ab30ff5396341da30a7ef162a1d6 0       file.ext
```

The leftmost field is the *mode* of the file, the next field is a *blob hash*,<sup>1</sup> the third field—which will always be zero unless you're in the middle of a conflicted merge—is the "staging slot" number, and the last field is the file's name, complete with forward slashes (but neither of these have any slashes in them so this doesn't really show it, plus MacOS uses forward slash anyway).

So:

> Now, the files exist on Github with the old capitalization ...

In fact, no files exist on GitHub at all.  The code that lets you browse your GitHub repository looks at the *commits* and uses that to figure out what the file names *would be*.  This stuff can be case sensitive, as it's not using actual files on your computer.  In general, you'll see what Git saved from the index here.

What you'll see therefore depends on how you look: if you look in the *work-tree* (work area on your computer), your computer can do case-folding, causing interesting lies.<sup>2</sup>  If you look at the *index*, you'll see Git's truth as extracted from a commit.  If you use GitHub's web browswer, you'll see truth filtered through your browser (which might potentially hide some things).

---

<sup>1</sup>The *blob hash* is determined by the file's content: Git doesn't store the actual file data directly in the index, but rather creates or re-uses one of its internal *blob objects* to hold the file's content.  In this way, any time you commit the same content you have in any other file held in any other commit, Git can just *re-use* the existing frozen-format internal-only file.  What's in the index, and therefore goes into each future commit, is the mode, path-name, and blob hash.

<sup>2</sup>On the Mac, file names are stored in NFD, which can interfere with the use of a file named `schön` or `agréable` that was first created on Linux, which just stores raw UTF-8 bytes however you write them.  See [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/999232/unicode-filenames-in-windows-vs-mac-os-x) for details.

Comment: Perfect! That is far more complicated than I assumed, but it's also nice to know it isn't a bug or a corrupted repo.

Comment: Note that it gets really messy when someone with a Linux system (I use Linux myself) creates two different files, one named `ip.h` and one named `IP.h` for instance. Your Windows or Mac (I use MacOS myself) literally can't hold both files in the work-tree, so you get just *one* of them in the work-tree even though *both* are in the index. The Git folks are working on mitigations for this in 2.24+ but they still haven't come up with my general scheme for handling this (which, I admit, is clumsy to use and tough to implement: they might come up with something better).